# How to prefer data vector which has a few peaks?

Tags: statistics, soft-question

In an information retrieval system, I have a vector of values which represent occurrences of a term in documents:

[image: This is a simplified example]

Term is preferred when it appears more frequently in very few documents. So, I need a numerical value to prefer vector which has few high peaks. For example:

```
TERM1 is preferred over TERM5 because it has one high peak compared to 4 high peaks

TERM1 is preferred over TERM6 because it has one high peak compared to 1 low value

TERM4 is preferred over TERM5 because it has one high peak and 3 low values compared to 4 high peaks

etc...
```

Is there any formula or calculated value that can give higher weight to preferred vectors?
p.s. I am not a mathematician

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statistics, there are different measures of concentration, which you could calculate for each term and then rank the terms based on the concentration measure. For example, you could use the [Herfindahl index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl%E2%80%93Hirschman_Index). It works as follows:

For each term $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and for each document $j=1,2,4,5$ (i.e., for each cell in your spreadsheet) you calculate the following:

$$s_{i,j}:=\frac{\text{frequency of term $i$ in document $j$}}{\text{sum of frequencies of term $i$ across all documents}}.$$

Then, you calculate for each term $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ the Herfindahl index:
$$H_i:=\sum_{j=1}^5 s_{i,j}^2=s_{i,1}^2+s_{i,2}^2+\ldots+s_{i,5}^2.$$

The index ranges from $\frac{1}{5}=0.2$ to 1. A higher number would be preferred in your example. Hence, you rank then the six terms based on the index in descending order starting with the highest index.

For example, term 1 has an index of $H_1=1$ and term 5 has an index of
$$H_5=\frac{6^2}{27^2}+\frac{8^2}{27^2}+\frac{6^2}{27^2}+\frac{7^2}{27^2}+\frac{0}{27^2}=\frac{36+64+36+49}{27^2}=\frac{185}{729}\approx 0.25<H_1=1.$$ Hence, term 1 is preferred over term 5.

There is one problem: The index only measures concentration. So, both term 1 and term 6 have an index of 1. To resolve ties, you could rank ties based on the highest peak (e.g., term 1 is preferred over term 6).

Edit: If you prefer that the index ranges from 0 to 1 (e.g., to make it comparable to an index calculated for a different number of documents), you can normalise it via
$$H^*_i:=\frac{H_i-1/n}{1-1/n},$$
where $n>1$ is the number of documents (in your example $n=5$).

Comment: Will the problem you mentioned appear only when we have a vector of: (zeros and a single non-zero value) ?

Comment: No, also, if the frequencies of one row are a multiple of the frequencies of another row. For example if term 1 has frequencies 1,1,2,9,0 and term 2 has frequencies 2,2,4,18,0 (not necessarily in that order), both have the same concentration, but I guess you would again prefer term 2 over term 1.

Comment: Okay. In my case, the concentration value will probably be multiplied by term's frequency in document to get that term's weight in that document, so I think the problem will disappear then. Right?

Comment: So, you want to multiply $H_i$ by the sum of the frequencies of term $i$ across all documents?

Comment: No.term's weight in a single document is usually $tf*idf$ . $tf$ is term's frequency in that document , $idf$ is usually: $log(N/n)$ where N is total documents number, and n is number of documents containing the term. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf. BUT idf does not distinguish between a term that appears few times in lots of documents and a term which appears very frequently in lots of documents. that's why i looked for an alternative measure to $idf$. so my new measure of term's weight in one document is ( term's frequency in document * term's concentration value ) i.e. $TF_id$ * $H_i$

Comment: I would not suggest multiplying two statistics that are on different scales. I suggest you pick one that is closest to what you want to measure. If you really need to use multiple statistics you have to think carefully about what their relationship is, rescale them appropriately, and combine them linearly with appropriate weights, e.g., $\lambda T_1 + (1-\lambda)T_2$ for two statistics $T_1,T_2$ on the same scale and a weight $0<\lambda<1$. Or you first rank them according to the more important statistic, and then use the second statistic only in case of ties (as I suggested in my answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106599/discussion-between-nina-and-toni).

Comment: What about the spacial case when n = 1 ?  normalized form is undefined